# can I show error message on html by using spring html

Tags: javascript, html, json, spring

I want to show an error on an HTML page. This is my controller:

```
Optional<Product> checkcode = productService.findByProcode(product.getProcode());
Optional<Product> checkname = productService.findByProname(product.getProname());
            if(checkcode.isPresent()){
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Product already exists!");
                 
            } else if (checkname.isPresent()) {
                 throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Product already exists!");
                 
            } else {
                productService.save(product1);
                System.out.println("New Product submission!");
            }
```

I want to show about message when I click and show error text on html that I use with spring.

Answer (score 0):

To show an error message on an HTML page in Spring, you can use the `ModelAndView` or `Model` class to add the error message to the model. Then, in your HTML page, you can access the error message using the `${attribute_name}` syntax.

Alternatively, you can use the `ResponseStatusException` class to return an HTTP error response to the client, which you can then display on the HTML page.